# What is the most efficient way to pass data between method invocations except using parameters in Java?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, instrumentation

I'm instrumenting a Android project for a specific testing purpose. I hope to transfer some information (e.g., an `infoObj` object) between method invocations. So the basic idea is to use a map (indexed by thread id to avoid concurrency issues) to store the `infoObj` before invoking a method, and then retrieve the `infoObj` from the map at the beginning of the invoked method body.

For example, here are two methods `f1` and `f2` where `f1` invokes `f2`.

```
void f1() {
  f2();
}

void f2() {
}
```

After instrumenting, they become:

```
void f1() {
  map.put(threadID, infoObj); // put infoObj into the map before invoking f2
  f2();
}

void f2() {
  map.remove(threadID); // get infoObj from the map at the beginning of f2
}
```

It works well in most of the cases. But when method invocations occur in a long loop, the instrumented program runs much slower than its original one. Using parameters to transfer is the best solution but unfortunately I cannot modify method definitions because program semantics may change.

What is the most efficient solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: What sort of map are you using?

Comment: So you are basically re-inventing the `ThreadLocal`? Have you tried that, also cleanup your map after use, else it will grow, grow grow (leading to excessive memory usage) the same for a `ThreadLocal` you need to clear it. Also size the map properly else growing/shrinking can take a lot of time as well as well as the type of map being used.

Comment: Why does it run much slower? Surely you've done profiling?

Comment: @rghome A HashMap

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried `ThreadLocal`. It is even slower...

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, it usually takes 5-10 times milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good way of doing this in Java. The main problem is that if you have multiple threads you need a map and maps are moderately expensive to use due to them having to calculate hashes and locate the item in the internal data structures.

Note that `HashMap` is also not thread-safe. You haven't said whether you have made it safe (e.g., using `Collections.synchronizedMap`). If you have, then you are better using `ConcurrentHashMap` which is much faster than a synchronized `HashMap`. If you haven't, making it thread-safe will only make it slower.

Incidentally, `ThreadLocal` has its own internal custom map implementation. I would imagine this is done for performance and that it must be faster than  using HashMap (else why bother?). So why you are seeing it as slower is a puzzle, unless you are not synchronizing, which might explain it.

I can suggest a few things:

1. You might be able to avoid the issue by predicting which thread you are in. I am not an expert on Android, but quite often certain bits of code can only be in certain threads and there might not be a lot of multi-threading going on unless you initiated it yourself. If that is the case you can just create a specific static for that code-point and reference it directly.
2. If you can't avoid using maps, you could scour the internet for faster map implementations.
3. Can you do the put operation elsewhere? Writing to a map is the slowest part, so if you can pre-populate it for the thread, that might speed things up. You also don't want to be allocating memory (calling new) in your instrumentation code, so make sure infoObj is pre-allocated and re-use it on each call.

Comment: This might be a use case for the new `ScopeLocal` feature which is currently tested as part of project Loom…